# Bedeutet "erst Anfang" hier "before" auf Englisch?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Bedeutet "erst Anfang" hier "before" auf Englisch?

> **Erst Anfang** der 70er-Jahre wurde das Bretton-Woods-System aufgegeben, das im Juni 1944 von Finanzministern und Notenbankchefs aus 44 Ländern in dem abgelegenen Örtchen Bretton Woods im US-Bundesstaat New Hampshire festlegten, um frühzeitig die Weichen für eine stabile Nachkriegsordnung zu stellen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nein, *erst Anfang* bedeutet im Englischen nicht *before*. Es bedeutet das Gegenteil. Die Phrase

> *erst Anfang* der 70er-Jahre

kann man zum Beispiel folgendermaßen übersetzen:

> - ***not** before the beginning* of the 70s
> - ***not** until the early* 70s

Comment: +1, sometimes the most appropriate rendering of a German word is a two-word expression. Personal anecdote: I once had a native speaker of English as a teacher who was unable to name "not until" as a translation of "erst 1970", and insisted that we should write "first 1970"! I can only assume that he hadn't really gotten German modal particles very well.

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstand.

> *Erst Anfang* der 70er-Jahre wurde das ... aufgegeben.

means almost literally:

> *Only at the start* of the nineteen seventies the ... was abandoned.
>   *Only in the beginning* of ... etc.

This means that it was not abandoned *before* the start of the nineteen seventies.